# Java - put the csv file in a array

Tags: java, arrays, csv

i'm a beginner in java.
Can you help me with this part?

i dont know how i can read a csv file with 3 columns and a lot of rows into a array.
I want change some columns and write again into the csv file.

I can read the file, but I can not change this.
I think it must somehow be loaded into an array or list?

Thanks

Comment: did you google it by any chance ? http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-csv-file/

Comment: I'd go with SuperCSV (http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html, http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_writing.html) and with a dedicated bean to represent each row instead of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). It is a csv parser library for Java.

Comment: Vielen Dank. Funktioniert Prima!

Answer (score 0):

1) Create 3 arrays (if you know the size already, else use arraylist) for each column type 
2) read file line by line.
3)For each line string, split it by ','
4) store the first value in first array, second in second and third in third
5) modify the value you want.
6) read values from array 1 separate by comma append second value and then comma and then third value and then new line character. this would give you a new line.
7) prepare string for whole file in above fashion.
8) store the modified content in a file